# Apparently large differences in univariate spline interpolation of data

Tags: python, signal-processing, interpolation, spline

I am trying to create a univariate spline interpolation in python to fit a large set of data and when i plot the two it seems like there is large differences. I have tried setting the smoothing factor to many different values (including zero so it has to go through every data point), but when i plot the two i am getting large differences.

```
##
# Univariate Spline Interpolation
##

## This function interpolates the data by creating multiple times the amount of points in the data set and fitting a spline to it
## Input:
# dataX - X axis that you corresponds to dataset
# dataY - Y axis of data to fit spline on (must be same size as dataX)
# multiple - the multiplication factor, default is 2 ( <1 - Less points, 1 - same amount of points, >1 - more points)
# order - order of spline, default is 4 (3 - Cubic, 4 - Quartic)
## Output
# splinedDataX - splined X Axis
# splinedDataY - splined Y Axis

def univariate_spline_interpolation( dataX, dataY, multiple=2, order=4):

    #Libraries
    from numpy import linspace,exp
    from numpy.random import randn
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline, LSQUnivariateSpline


    #Find sizes of x and y axis for comparison and multiple
    sizeX = len(dataX)
    sizeY = len(dataY)


    #Error catching
    if(sizeX != sizeY):
        print "Data X axis and Y axis must have same size"
        return

    if(multiple <= 0):
        print "Order must be greater than 0"
        return

    if(order < 1 or order >5):
        print "Order must be 1 <= order <= 5"
        return

    #Create Spline
    s = UnivariateSpline(dataX, dataY, k=3, s=0)   
    # s is smoothing factor so spline doesn't shoot off in between data points
    #Positive smoothing factor used to choose the number of knots.
    #Number of knots will be increased until the smoothing condition is satisfied:
    # sum((w[i]*(y[i]-s(x[i])))**2,axis=0) <= s
    #If None (default), s=len(w) which should be a good value if 1/w[i] is an estimate of the standard deviation of y[i].
    #If 0, spline will interpolate through all data points.

    #Create new axis based on numPoints
    numPoints = sizeX * multiple   #Find mumber of points for spline
    startPt = dataX[1]   #find value of first point on x axis
    endPt = dataX[-1]   #find value of last point on x axis
    splinedDataX = linspace(startPt, endPt, numPoints)   #create evenly spaced points on axis based on start, end, and number of desired data points

    #Create Y axis of splined Data
    splinedDataY = s(splinedDataX)   #Create new Y axis with numPoints etnries of data splined to fit the original data

    return splinedDataX, splinedDataY

##
# Text Cubic Spline
##

splinedX, splinedY = univariate_spline_interpolation(sensorTimestamp, filteredData[1], multiple=1)

print "old x data"
print "length", len(sensorTimestamp)
print "Starts", sensorTimestamp[0]
print "Ends", sensorTimestamp[-1]
print ""

print "new x data"
print "length", len(splinedX)
print "multiple", len(splinedX)/len(filteredData[1])
print "Starts", splinedX[0]
print "Ends", splinedX[-1]
print ""

print "old y data"
print "length", len(filteredData[1])
print "Starts", filteredData[1][0]
print "Ends", filteredData[1][-1]
print ""

print "new y data"
print "length", len(splinedY)
print "Starts", splinedY[0]
print "Ends", splinedY[-1]


difference = []
for i in splinedY:
    difference.append(splinedY[i] - filteredData[1][i])

plt.figure(figsize=(20,3))
plt.plot(sensorTimestamp, filteredData[1], label='Non-Splined', marker='*')
plt.plot(splinedX, splinedY, label='Splined')
plt.plot(sensorTimestamp, difference, label='Difference', ls='--')
plt.title(' BW Filtered Data from LED 1')
plt.axis([19, 30, -300, 300])
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Output print:

```
old x data
length 14690
Starts 0.0
Ends 497.178565979

new x data
length 14690
multiple 1.0
Starts 0.0555429458618
Ends 497.178565979

old y data
length 14690
Starts 50.2707843894
Ends 341.661410048

new y data
length 14690
Starts 416.803282313
Ends 341.661410048
```

[Here is the output Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvGd1.png)

As you can see the differences are huge but on the graph the data appears to be the exact same points (or very close).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you calculate the difference with

```
splinedY[i] - filteredData[1][i]
```

the data isn't correctly aligned on the x axis and that you therefore substract values that don't lie on the same point of the x axis. The splined data has timestamps slighlty shifted to the right, because in the `univariate_spline_interpolation` function

```
startPt = dataX[1]
```

while the number of points is the same as in the input x data. This line should probably be changed to

```
startPt = dataX[0]
```

Comment: The problem persists (just the difference is slightly shifted), when i changed the line to dataX[0].

Answer (score 0):

I think the computation for difference by

splinedY[i] - filteredData[1][i]

is fundamentally questionable. 'splinedY[i]' are computed from evenly spaced X values (splinedDataX) within univariate_spline_interpolation(). The splinedDataX will not be the same as the 'sensorTimestamp'; therefore comparing their corresponding Y values would not make sense.

After googling about how the for loop should be coded in python, I think the problem culprit is in the statement of

for i in splinedY:

The 'i' in this statement will be the array element's value, instead of index. The correct syntax will be

for i in range(len(splinedY)):

Comment: Hmm, i never though about this.But the adjacent datapoints are close anway, why are the differences so huge?

Comment: I am not familiar with Python. But are you sure the "i' in "for i in splinedY" really means the index of the array and is not the actual value of the array element?

Comment: you're correct i should be using `for indx, val in enumerate(splinedY)` which now results in much smaller deviations, but they are still huge compared to what they should be

Comment: @OP: You might want to post the new result (numeric data and graph) so that people can help.

Comment: @user3123955 ...and maybe dump your input data somewhere (pastbin or so) and post a link, so that we can try out your code.